# Can't extend spacing on Tailwind

Tags: node.js, extend, spacing, tailwind-css

I'm trying to extend the spacing on Tailwind, but I can't make it work. I did my research and I made the changes in the `tailwind.config.js`, but when I use the class in the HTML, it doesn't exist.

PS: I understand that there is no need to run the build

*tailwind.config.js*

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      spacing: {
        '1/3': '33,333333%',
        '2/3': '66,666667%'
      }
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just checked your config and it does create all the classes. The problem is that `33,333333%` and `66,666667%` are not valid CSS values.

Unlike in Spanish, you have to use decimal points, not commas:

```js
theme: {
  extend: {
    spacing: {
      '1/3': '33.333333%',
      '2/3': '66.666667%',
    },
  },
},
```

`33,333333%` is an invalid property value:

[image]

`33.333333%` works fine:

[image]

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-night-tqwq4)

Comment: Okay thanks,I changed it, but it still don't working. if you need more information just ask for it

Comment: How do you build your CSS?

Comment: "build": "postcss css/tailwind.css -o public/build/tailwind.css" in package.json "scripts"
then in console: npm run build

Comment: I've just added a CodeSandbox link with PostCSS setup.

Comment: ohh, i dont know how to use it, sorry
Don't worry, I will try to resolve it, thanks for the help